# Handling signed edges

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to create positive (friend) and negative (enemy) links between turtles. I can use something like the following to store the edge type:

```
links-own[
 sign ;1 is positive, -1 is negative 
]
```

but is there any way to get functions like `link-neighbor?` and `link-neighbors` to report only friends (or enemies)?

As always, thank you for any help/advice.

Answer (score 6):

#### Using other-end

You could select link and call `other-end`:

```
show [other-end] of my-links with [sign = 1]  ; friends
show [other-end] of my-links with [sign = -1] ; enemies
```

#### Option with link breeds

But maybe it would be better to start with two link breeds:

```
undirected-link-breed [enemies enemy]
undirected-link-breed [friends friend]
```

Using link breeds is simple - just replace link/links in your commands:

```
ask turtle 0 [create-friend-with turtle 1]
ask turtle 0 [create-enemy-with turtle 2 ]
```

The code is more clear then:

```
show [friend-neighbors] of turtle 0
show [enemy-neighbors] of turtle 0

ask turtle 0 [show my-friends]
ask turtle 0 [show my-enemies]
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to have two breeds. In a network, each edge represents a relationship and 'friend' is a different relationship than 'enemy'. So the code is not only clear, but the thinking is as well. This will also make it easier to do things like find the distance between nodes only going through friends.

Comment: @JenB Thanks! Agree about relationships. Although it may depend on the model purpose - one could extend the model to cooling (or warming) relationships :)